# rosparam returns string not yaml array

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to define an array in yaml file and load into parameter server in launch file.  The following bit of code

```
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue temp;  
nhp.searchParam("/r_arm/position/my_param", temp);  
ROS_ASSERT(temp.getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeArray);
```

Fails with the assertion that "temp" is an XmlRpcValue::TypeString not an array, even though

```
rosparam get /r_arm/position/my_param
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

shows the array.

They yaml code looks like:

```
{r_arm:{position:{
     my_param:[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    ,my_param2:[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    },force:{ 
       ...
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

(ros Groovy version)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97396/rosparam-returns-string-not-yaml-array/) by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2013-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try to replace

```
nhp.searchParam("/r_arm/position/my_param", temp);
```

with

```
nhp.getParam("/r_arm/position/my_param", temp);
```

`searchParam()` searches the namespace tree upwards and returns the **name** of the first existing parameter, not its value. You still would have to call `getParam()` to retrieve the value. The `XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue` is implicitly casted into a string reference when passed to `searchParam()` and therefore has type `TypeString` afterwards.

See http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Parameters#Searching_for_Parameters for further details.

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 1266 on 2013-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2